# Need some guidance with trignometric math problem

Tags: trigonometry

Problem question that I am trying to solve goes:

```
sin(x)^2 * tan (x) = 0.00574

Solve for x
```

Tried the following:

```
Reduced it down to sin(x)^3/sqrt(1-sin(x)^2). But not sure how to further proceed.
```

Thanks!

Comment: By $\sin(x)^2$, I suppose you mean $\sin2(x)$, ans similarly for $\sin(x)^3$?

Comment: Apologies - should have formatted better.   $sin(x)^2$

Comment: Doesn't appear to have a simple solution. Would a numerical solution (such as Newton's method) suffice?

Comment: Yes, of course. Appreciate it.